# get_attachment from functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, colorbox

I'm trying to open an image with a lightbox (colorbox) and when it did, have a button that opens a link to it's *attachment-page*.

I made the attribute `data-att=""` were the link to the attachment-page should get.

Here is what i have in **functions.php** right now:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_colorbox');
  function add_colorbox($content) {
    global $post;
    $att_url = wp_get_attachment_link($id);
    $pattern ="/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
    $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 class="fotos" data-att="'. $att_url .'" title="'.$post->post_title.'"$6>';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
  return $content; 
  }
```

So with `$att_url = get_attachment_link($id);` im trying to get the attachment link and pass it to the `data-att="..."` with no luck yet...

Comment: You have not set $id to anything so within this function it will have no value.

Comment: Yes, but can you give a suggestion how to get it?

Comment: So what i need is to get the id of the attachment image...any suggestions?